# saving a variable with a button but not reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript

So I have a website which there are about 10 to 20 forms that need to be filled out throughout the page, however in the middle there is a section which asks if you want to buy something. How I wanted this set up was you could just click "buy" (a button set up to set a variable in an array) and continue on filling in your info. However it occurred to me that if I did that the page would reload with you attempted to press "buy", effectively clearing all of those fields you just spent time putting information into. Is there some way I can have a "buy" button that sends the sku of the item to an array without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have a hidden input field that will contain whether or not the user is buying this item.  The value is updated when the button is clicked.

However, I might suggest a checkbox instead.  Perhaps the user will decide that they don't actually want to buy this item after they click the button.  Having a checkbox allows the user to change their mind.

Comment: this is a good idea, however I forgot to mention that we hope to implement a cart on the left side that will take the array of purchased items, and output the label, description, price, etc of the items that they chose. Would a checkbox be able to set something to a variable?

Comment: @user1650459, Yes, you can implement any JavaScript on any input element that you would like.  If there is another clear way for the user to remove the item from their cart, then maybe the checkbox isn't necessary.  But in any case, consider usability first, and code second.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing what your doing, and since you didn't post any code, I cant only give you vague advice.

I'd suggest using sessions to store the data OR use AJAX to pass the value to another page.